# Materialize css carousel doesn't work in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, materialize

I'm new to Angular and materialize and i faced a problem. I imported materialize successfully into Angular, materialize css elements work but js elements don't. Carousel and other elements such as select, don't show up in my component. Just an empty spot.

Here is package.json

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.11",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.6.55",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.0",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "ngx-materialize": "^6.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.11",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

here is angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js",
   "node_modules/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
            ]
          },
```

Here is my component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare const M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recommended-posts',
  templateUrl: './recommended-posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recommended-posts.component.css']
})
export class RecommendedPostsComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    M.AutoInit();
    
   }
 
}
```

and html file:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!">test message</a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
  </div>
```

I i tried to put js code as  to html page and even jquery code from the materilize website. But doesn't help either.

This solution i looked up on a question on this website but the result is the same.

Everything seems to be imported, but i don't know why it doesn't work. What is my mistake? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example (it isn't mine). I think that issue is that you are initializing carousel from ngOnInit but it is too early since child component won't be rendered at that point.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materialize-carousel?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It started to work, however, i receive an error because of this import line. It is red  " import M from 'materialize-css'; "    says it's not a module. What can i do about it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: How about this using import * as M from 'materialize-css';

Comment: However i get another problem. Without *ngFor it works but with it stop working just a blank page. Why is that happening?